# Full width DatePicker view

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a custom DialogFragment that I am presenting fullscreen.  The view has 2 tabs, one for setting date, on for setting time.

Here is the xml layout that contains the DatePicker view.

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:datePickerMode="calendar"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PrimaryAccent" />
```

However I cannot get the DatePicker to extend the full width of the screen.

[image]

There is a fair amount of info out there, however it seems the answer in always to use a DatePickerDialog, which I cannot use as I have a custom dialog to contain the DatePicker view.  Is it possible to extend the calendar to cover the full width of the screen?

Comment: Looks like the DatePicker may size itself based on the resolution of the screen. Have you tried hard-coding a specific `dp` value instead of `match_parent` to see if the size changes? If so, you could use multiple `dimens.xml` files to size it based on the resolution. If not, perhaps you could center it horizontally to at least make it look nicer.

Comment: @JimRhodes ha yeah, center horizontally is what I have now.  It does help, but would be awesome if that header spanned the full width.  Unfortunately adjusting the width has no effect.  Looks like the view itself might get bigger, but the header and calendar within the view never change size.

Comment: If you can query the height of the header, you could draw your own background behind it.

Comment: Its not part of the public DatePicker api, so doing anything there would be a bit dangerous.